# Methods and variables

Tags: android

Asking this question again about my code. It is not working correctly and I have called them in my XML, but they are still not working. Here is the code: The problem code are highlighted in bold. I am posting my XML as well. Java code at the top and my XML code is at the bottom.

```
     package app.com.example.android.shoutoutapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.R;
import android.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textTargetUri;
    ImageView targetImage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button buttonAddPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_photo);
        textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);
        targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

        buttonAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }});
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
                targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/imageView" />




     <TextView
            android:text= "Thot of The Day!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/text_shout_out"



            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_photo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Photo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_shout_out"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="131dp"
            android:onClick="LoadImage"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/targeturi"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Atleast specify, what is not working in your code.

Comment: I have. Their in **. I could make them red. The stars show what's wrong. The code at the beginning. It's not executing

Comment: You can't run Java and XML code together like that. Or, do not provide sample code from two different files in the same code block, which might be what you are doing. From your question,  it isn't clear if this is a COMPILE time error, Run time error, or IDE error (compile time).

Comment: post your complete java code in separate block, then anyone can help you with your problem.

Comment: Most likely you have an XML resource error, which is breaking the Resource file compilation. Or you have imported the wrong Resource file (sometimes people import android.R instead of their own resource file). Look at the imports and make sure you see "import my.package.R;"

Comment: The information provided is very limited please post more code so we get the whole picture. Also please describe what is not working specifically?

Comment: Ok. The XML and the Java code aren't together. That's for the questioning portion of this. Their not together in Android studio.

Comment: I'll edit and give the whole Java code. The stars are where the problems are.

Comment: I've posted all the Java code

Comment: You're importing `android.R`, that means you can't find `R.layout.activity_main`. Import your package instead. You should also avoid importing all `android.*` package.

Comment: I'm looking to import my package, but I'm having a difficult time with that . it's not showing up in the library

Answer (score 2):

Your `ImageView` has id `imageView` instead of `targetimage`

Change your `ImageView` in xml, like this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/targetimage" />
```